# Is Flash installed by default?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

Is Flash installed by default? If so I'd like to uninstall flash. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not installed by default. You can check if it's installed by entering in the address bar of your browsers `about:plugins` or here https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html